# Best format for importing large dataset into Matlab from web APIs

Tags: matlab

I'm designing a webapi for large datasets (timeseries) that have to be accessible in an efficient manner by different clients, one of which is Matlab.

At the moment the API is returning a Json encoded array of records {datetime, datetime, string, double} and this is ok but Matlab is painfully slow importing a Json to a cell array: for 10k records, the Api returns in less than 500ms and Matlab parsing takes 15s.

Which is the best format we can use to import data into matlab in you opinion?

Comment: How are you parsing? It might be possible to improve this. Could you provide an example json?

Comment: Have you seen the [Database Toolbox](http://fr.mathworks.com/products/database/) ? It's quite fast with MySQL.

Comment: It may be that a large proportion of your time is spent not really in parsing the JSON, but in parsing the dates. You might want to try running the MATLAB profiler on your JSON parsing code to confirm/refute that.

Comment: @Ratbert the data have to be received via WebAPI, no direct access to any DB

Comment: @Daniel we're using both the native json parser that comes with the [webread](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) function configuring the [weboptions](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) with Content-Type 'json'.

Content-Type 'text' => string result, 500ms
Content-Type 'json' => struct array, 15sec

We also tried [Jsonlab](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi?jsonlab) toolbox but is even slower.

Comment: @SamRoberts actually the timing is before even converting the ISO8601 string into a matlab Datetime. 15 seconds from Json array to Array of Structs {string, string,string,double}.

Comment: @Daniel you can find a sample file [here](http://filebin.ca/1v1hao7YsbMP)